# Hadoop Pig job not running

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, jobs

I am testing hadoop, as of now I have :

1) localhost:8088 working

2) localhost:50070 working

3) I created a few files on hdfs

Then I launch pig, and do a LOAD on a file, and then a FILTER, and then a DUMP.

When I DUMP, pig display info about the starting of the mapreduce.

It ends with a sentence like :

"MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete" + "Running Jobs are [job_xxx]".

So I think the job is launched. I even see it as an ACCEPTED App on the hadoop interface on localhost:8088. But then nothing happens : it is stucked at 0% complete :-(

So, the job is "ACCEPTED" but never goes to RUNNING :-(

Should I do something to make my grunt/pig command lines instructions to run ??

Thanks.

JR.

PS: I can't make any copy paste from my job environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I unblocked the situation while getting aware that my hard drive was 90% full. At this level, hadoop refuses to write anymore logs. I just had to delete some (big !) files to get it running again...